# Can't find driver (Intel UHD Graphics 605)

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics

Installed Ubuntu 18.04, Intel UHD Graphics 605.

In Software Updater, all checkboxes inside Other Software are checked.

I go to Additional Drivers. And I dont see a drivers for my laptop.

Why doesn't Ubuntu find a suitable driver? Now my laptop screen does not display well. Fonts are large, windows sometimes do not fit on the screen.

How can I find a suitable driver? My laptop specifications: Intel UHD Graphics 605, Intel Pentium N5000 Processor.

Answer (score 1):

Intel UHD Graphics drivers are in the OS kernel, so you need not search for them.

However, the [Pentium N5000](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/128990/intel-pentium-silver-n5000-processor-4m-cache-up-to-2-70-ghz.html) CPU fails to meet the [minimum hardware requirements of Ubuntu 18.04](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements). A less demanding flavour of Ubuntu, such as Lubuntu [18.04 LTS 32-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/18.04/release/lubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-i386.iso),  [18.04 LTS 64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/18.04/release/lubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso), or [19.04 64-bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/disco/release/lubuntu-19.04-desktop-amd64.iso), *may* work. It seems your CPU may meet the [requirements of Lubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu/AdvancedMethods#Processor_.28CPU.29), even though it does not meet the requirements of Ubuntu.

Please make sure to [verify the checksums](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) of what you download before you generate the LiveDVD or LiveUSB used to install it.

Comment: Now I'm wondering what part of the requirements it is failing to meet. Ubuntu itself certified them for 18.04 at least. https://certification.ubuntu.com/catalog/component/dmi:Intel(R)Pentium(R)SilverN5000CPU@1.10GHz